# Numbers on the vertices of cube

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

We write $0$ on $7$ vertices of a cube and $1$ on the other vertex
. We can select an edge in each step and add $1$ to the numbers written on its ends.
Prove gcd of the numbers written on vertices is always $1$.

My "solution" is as follows. Please check it:

Assume for the sake of contradiction that gcd of all the vertices = $d > 1.$ Then after some finite number of moves note that we can always go back to initial configuration.  If the gcd of all the vertices is $d>1$ then subtracting multiples of $d$ will result in multiples of $d$, after we subtracted from every vertices, we will be left with multiple of $d$ at the last step. But $d > 1$ so its multiple must also be $> 1$, which contradicts the initial configuration. Thus, gcd must be $1$.

Comment: What does "we can always go back to initial configuration" mean?  I would have thought you keep adding to the numbers, so you cannot go back.

Comment: Your argument is only showing that the reverse of a process to get a configuration with gcd $d$ cannot be "subtracting multiples of $d$".

Comment: @Henry by that i mean we can go back to initial configuration by reversing the steps we did

Comment: @plop can u elaborate more please

Comment: There is no more to elaborate. You only talk about subtracting multiples of $d$. There are many steps that you can do that don't consist of subtracting multiples of $d$. For example, subtracting $1$ on two vertices that are joined by an edge.

Comment: This problem can be solved by coming up with an invariant, a magnitude that you compute from the values on the vertices that after each step it doesn't change. Then you show that the value for the initial cube is different from that of a cube with multiples of $d$ on all vertices.

Comment: @plop u mean parity of the vertex at each step?

Comment: Parity shows that $2$ cannot be a common divisor. It does not help direct with odd  common divisors, but it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: okay thanks ill investigate more then :)

Comment: Well, parity would help you to exclude $2$ as a final common factor. You could involve remainders modulo $d$ or just an arbitrary prime. Observe also that the remainders of the differences of the numbers in vertices that connected by an edge is left invariant after one operation done on those vertices.

Comment: @plop u mean like every time we make a move, if we color vertices with two colors alternatively the sum of numbers in one color is one more than the other? I'm sorry i didnt specify what did coloring vertices with two colors alternatively mean but i think u understand

Comment: Yes, that is an invariant that takes different values for the initial cube and for a cube with all vertices multiple of $d$.

Answer (score 1):

View the vertices of the cube as the set
$$V:=\{\pm1\}^3=\{(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)\},$$
and for each vertex $v\in V$, define its 'weight' $w(v)$ as the product of its coordinates, so that
$$w(1,1,1)=1,\qquad w(1,-1,1)=-1,\qquad w(-1,-1,-1)=-1.$$
Denote the number on a vertex $v\in V$ by $n_v$. Then in the initial configuration of the cube you have $n_v=1$ for some $v\in V$, and $n_w=0$ for all other $w\in V$, and taking the weighted sum we have
$$w=\sum_{v\in V}w(v)n_v=\pm1.$$
depending on whether the weight of $n_v$. Now note that for any edge of the cube, the two vertices at its ends have opposite weights. This means the weighted sum
$$w=\sum_{v\in V}w(v)n_v,$$
remains unchanged when we add $1$ to the vertices at both ends of an edge. It follows that the weighted sum $w$ remains unchanged, so $w=\pm1$. It follows that $\gcd_{v\in V}n_v=1$.

Comment: Nice! In plain English, if you color the vertices white and black so adjacent vertices are different colors, and let $B$ be the sum of the black numbers and $W$ the sum of the white numbers, then the difference $B-W$ is invariant, so is always $\pm1$. The gcd of the vertices divides $B-W$, so the gcd is always one.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, that's nice and clear! I just wanted to make sure that it is clear that it is possible to give adjacent vertices different colors. It may not be so clear for those that are not so used to spatial/visual thinking.